# Convert name strings with diacritics into e-mail compatible format (SQL, C# or PowerAutomate)

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a bit of experience with SQL and Power Platform/Logic Apps and am at the very beginning of learning C#.

I have a large SQL table with names (first names and last names) that are supposed to be used to create email addresses in Azure.
I want the display names of the emails to stay original, but I have to remove the German special characters äöüß and replace them with ae, oe, ue and ss and some characters with diacritics é, à etc that I need to replace with e or a etc.

Now, I'm wondering if I should create a view in SQL with two new columns that will convert the characters, or if I should create a logic app that will do all the replacements (and wrap that in a custom api) or if that would be a good project for my first azure function in C-Sharp (to be wrapped in a custom api).

I'm curious as to where in the system to handle the issue, and if there are any standard procedures available to handle this. I cannot be the first one to have exactly that problem.
A Google search gave me 20 different ways to handle it, all of which seemed a bit awkward or didn't work for me.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you elaborate on "all of which seemed a bit awkward or didn't work for me"? Otherwise, there's a good chance you'll get similar answers here. It's also unclear what this is needed for? I don't currently see why an `é` should not be possible to put in an email.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't really have the tools for this. Much easier to do this in C# (or possibly as a SQLCLR function written in C#). You can use `string.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is that this can be done directly using SQL commands itself. Below is a sample of data that I'm working on.

[image]

I tried creating another Colum called "**FullName**" and use `CONCAT()` operation to concat the **FirstName** and **LastName**.

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLENAME>
ADD [FullName] varchar(50);

Update <TABLENAME>
SET FullName = CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName);
```

[image]

Now I have used `REPLACE()` Function to replace all the required German special Characters.

```
UPDATE <TableName>
SET FullName = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(FullName,'ä','ae'),'ö','oe'),'ü','ue'),'ß','ss'),'é','e'),'à','a')
WHERE 'FullName'!='';
```

[image]

Now you can use the Full Name to be the Display Name while maintaining the original values in our table i.e., Firstname and LastName.

Alternatively, You can do that same using the logic apps too using `Execute a SQL query (V2)` action.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Below is the codeview of my Logic App

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "select * from Table1"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "Update Table1\nSET FullName = CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName);"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "UPDATE Table1\nSET FullName = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(FullName,'ä','ae'),'ö','oe'),'ü','ue'),'ß','ss'),'é','e'),'à','a')\nWHERE 'FullName'!='';"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-2",
                    "connectionName": "sql-2",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```